# How can I make a game that allows players to earn a certain NFT or crypto currency after they beat a boss?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, games, cryptoeconomics

I am an aspiring game developer and my friends and I have recently decided to make a game that centers around a main storyline and characters that can be defeated for crypto or NFT's. Could you give a basic description about how we would go about doing this? Thank you. rgg

Comment: More info please: does it have to be real crypto or is that just your in-game story? Does it have to be an existing cryptocurrency or will you make one just for your game?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a basic erc 721 contract where only the owner (i.e. you) can mint a NFT.

When a player kills the boss, you have a function in your backend that calls the smart contract as the owner, tell the smart contract to mint a 'boss slayed' NFT and sends it to the address of your player.

That means you need to ask new player for their wallet address and keep that in your DB

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this in such a way that the user pays for all the gas fees?

Comment: Yes, you need to create the transaction in your backend and present the transaction to your user through a metamask prompt for him/her to sign the transaction and mint the NFT. It's possible but a little bit harder than just minting it and sending it. Give me an upvote if my first answer was helpful to you! Thanks!